# perl: print remaining string only if there is no character before the matched value.

Tags: string, perl

The following prints the entire content of the line after "B. "

```
perl -ne'print if /B[.] (.*)/s' $string > file
```

How can I match/print the line only if there is no other character before the "B. "? In other words, if there is a character before the `"B. "` ie. `"TAB."` skip the line / do not print.

The correct "B." is always on a new line, the only correct line to match appears as follows:

```
B. some text here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex with a leading carat indicates that the expression should match only if it is the first item on the line. The pattern `/^B[.] (.*)/s` should get you the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Put `^` in front of the `B`. It means match the word starts with `B`. So your regex should be `/^B\. (.*)/`. Then no need you `s` flag in your pattern match.